# Name doesn't exists in Namespace error in XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have a WPF Application with" a Custom Settings Provider (class Settings).

in my XAML File I try some Data binding but I get the error message:
"The name Settings does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"

In my XAML file I have:

```
 xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
  .
  . 
  . 
 DataContext="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}">
```

in my Settings class I have:

```
  namespace MyProject.Properties {
```

Why do I get that error message? Wenn I type the "properties:" then the intellisense finds the "Settings" and also the "Default" entry.

The funny thing is, that it is an old project which did compile with the VS2017 last year without problems. Then I didn't touch is and now I have that error

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the target to "Release" then re-build.

Comment: Thank you I think I found the problem. I had some lines above a click-event with a method that didn't exists. Seems to be a following error, after I created the method, the error message disappeared